# When compiling code antivirus says it's virus and delete it

Tags: c++, antivirus

Hi i try to make code in c++. This code only makes text file easy encrypted and save into a new file. And when i compile this code antivirus says, it is virus/spyware Gen:Variant.Kazy.20825. I dont know why it is virus. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

void controlParameters(int argc){  //check if input parameters are ok
    if(argc == 1){
        cout << "Pokud chcete text zasifrovat, spustte program s parametrem: -enc \"Nazev_souboru.txt\"\n";
        cout << "Pokud ho chcete desifrovat, spustte program s parametrem: -dec \"Nazev_souboru.txt\"\n";
    }else if(argc > 3){
        cout << "Moc parametru. Spustte si program bez parametru.\n";
    }else if(argc < 3){
        cout << "Chybi jeden parametr. Spustte si program bez parametru.\n";
    }else{
        cout << "Vsechno vypada zatim dobre\n";
    }
}

void encryption(string &file);  //encrypt text file
void decryption(string &file);  //decrypt text file
bool controlFile(string &file); //check if file can be opened

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    controlParameters(argc);
    string file;
    file = argv[2];
    if(controlFile(file)){

    }else{
        cout << "Soubor nesel nacist." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Ukonceno.\nZmacknete ENTER pro pokracovani..."<<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

bool controlFile(string &file){
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(file);
    if(ifs.is_open()){
        ifs.close();
        return true;
    }else{
        ifs.close();        
        return false;
    }
}

void encryption(string &file){
    ifstream ifs;
    ofstream ofs;
    string line;    
    ifs.open(file);
    ofs.open("encrypt.txt");
    if(ifs.is_open()){
        while(!ifs.eof()){
            getline(ifs,line);
            int a = line.length();
            int i = 0;
            while(i < a){               
                ofs << ((char)(line[i]^100));               
            }
            line.clear();
            ofs << "\n";
        }
    }else{
        cout << "Nelze nacist soubor" << endl;
    }
}

void decryption(string &file){
    ifstream ifs;
    ofstream ofs;
    string line;
    ifs.open(file);
    ofs.open("decrypt.txt");
    if(ifs.is_open()){
        while(!ifs.eof()){
            getline(ifs,line);
            int a =line.length();
            int i = 0;
            while(i < a){               
                ofs << ((char)(line[i]^100));               
            }
            line.clear();
            ofs << "\n";
        }
    }else{
        cout << "Nelze nacist soubor" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your antivirus program gives you annoying false positives, stop using it. (And, by the way, your code is buggy. It will fail if there are any `d`'s in the file.)

Comment: Also, your `while` loops will loop forever.

Comment: maybe your antivirus doesn't like Czech language :-)

Comment: has been asked so many times.. there's a search function for that!

Answer (score 5):

It's good practice to exclude your source-control directories from virus scanners; they can cause performance and locking problems even if there are *no* false positives while performing source-control actions or compiling (I've seen it happen several times).

So if only to make your programming experience more reliable, disable the virus scanner on those directories.

You may still want to scan the final, released version of your executable to help avoid false positives: after all, even if it's not your fault the virus scanner chokes, it's not a good impression to leave behind on a user.

Answer (score 4):

Antivirus software uses "heuristics" to determine what is a virus and what isn't. So it looks for patterns in the file that does things that it finds suspicious. I can't see anything directly wrong in your code, so I suspect it's a "false-positive". I personally don't like antivirus software, it causes more problems than it solves...

By the way, you could add the "output filename" to your encrypt/decrypt function, and make them one function! ;)

Comment: thx for your answer. And yes, i can make encrypt and decrypt function in one.

Comment: I also got some Kazy false positives on VirusTotal for [this build](https://github.com/lmstearn/Bigger-Directories). It's likely some heuristic based algos need a rejig,