# C files not running properly in VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, g++

I am using vscode for while now, and I ran smooth but for the past few days I am having an issue in compiling and running C source files...
Like when I am running:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello");    
    return 0;
}
```

Vscode terminal shows the following error:-

```
Program 'h1.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:83
+ ... ARORA\Desktop\rough\" ; if ($?) { gcc h1.c -o h1 } ; if ($?) { .\h1 }
+                                                                    ~~~~.
At line:1 char:83
+ ... ARORA\Desktop\rough\" ; if ($?) { gcc h1.c -o h1 } ; if ($?) { .\h1 }
+                                                                    ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

But when I run:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("hello");    
    return 0;
}
```

It gets successfully compiled and executed, and other cpp files are also working...
I don't know what is the problem, please help...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will try to find the duplicate for this. I am almost certain you are running an Anti Virus and it is randomly freaking out that your executable is malware. You need to disable AV scanning on your work directories. AV and software compiling does not mix.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460776/when-compiling-code-antivirus-says-its-virus-and-delete-it

Comment: Yes, you are right I disabled Real-time scanning and the code worked, but now could you please help me with which all 'work directories' have to be excluded from real-time scanning.

Comment: You should exclude the directories that you write binary files into like .o, .obj, .exe, .dll, .lib, .a, etc. I just exclude everything including the source code too. Since I put everything on Git somewhere that is Visual Studio's default C:\Users\my-user\source\repos I used to put everything into Documents\Working or other directories. The exact name doesn't matter but if you keep all your projects in one place you can exclude that whole directory. And oh yeah one time file names got too long for Windows and I had to put everything into C:\W . Heh.